# Different reponses for mongodb query using callback and promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Have you any idea why I don't get any error in the first example? But if I use a callback, I get MongoTimeoutError.

```js
await server.stop();
try {
    const r = await db.things.insertOne({ a: 1 }); // no error, r is undefined
    assert(!r);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
await server.restart();
const r = await db.things.insertOne({ a: 1 });
assert(r.insertedCount === 1);
```

```js
db.things.insertOne({ a: 1 }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        //"MongoTimeoutError" "Server selection timed out after 10000 ms"
        return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(result);
})
```

In options I have `bufferMaxEntries = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with mongodb driver. See the JIRA [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/NODE/issues/NODE-2136?filter=allopenissues)